# При определении местоположения через android.location не меняется время - time

Tags: android, kotlin, location

Есть небольшое приложение, которое отправляет координаты местоположения мобильного устройства на сервер. Данные (широта, долгота и время) получаю из LocationManager и записываю в базу данных. Заметил такую проблему, что если устройство находится в неподвижном состоянии и координаты не меняются - не меняется и время их определения. Как это можно исправить?

```
    private fun handleLocation(location: Location) {
    onLocationChange(location)
    PositionLogger.save(
        location = listOf(
            Triple(
                location.latitude,
                location.longitude,
                location.time
            )
        ),
        mode = PositionLogger.SaveMode.ALL
    )
```

Comment: или заменить onLocationChange (где из названия следует, что вызывается только при смене позиции) на что-нибудь другое, или просто автоматически записывать новые данные каждые 2-3-5-20 секунд (по желанию)

Comment: А Вам обязательно фиксировать время из location.time? Оно действительно не будет обновляться, если координаты не обновились - так устроено... Правильнее будет фиксироват время на устройстве: Date().time

Либо, если принципиально нужно из координат, но оно не изменилось, то надо завести переменную типа Long, куда Вы положите последнее значение и потом сравнивайте. если они совпали, то берете Date().time, а если нет, то берете location.time и кладете ее же в эту переменную для будущего сравнения